# Are there high crime areas in Japan that I should avoid?

Tags: safety, japan, security, tokyo, nightlife

According to the this [link](http://www.travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1148.html) (in the "Crime" section), I should avoid the areas of "Roppongi, Shinjuku (especially the area of Kabuki-cho), Shibuya, and Ikebukuro" in Tokyo, due to them being high crime areas.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Generally speaking, the security warnings of the U.S. government are highly exaggerating in my opinion.

Comment: For example I just read the Threats and Crime section of Switzerland and Liechtenstein, and as a local I can assure you that it is just ridiculous.

Comment: I've never avoided any area of any city in Japan at any hour of day or night.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't find any government numbers to back up my anecdotal evidence, but Shinjuku, Shibuya and Ikebukuro are all very safe - much safer than their equivalents in London, New York or any other 'world' city. I've spent many nights in each, in varying states of sobriety, and never had any problems at all. I've lost my wallet a few times (on trains, in bars and the like) and never failed to retrieve it - either at the time from a fellow reveller, or at a police box (koban) later on.

Kabuki-cho is the closest thing you'll get to a 'red light' district. Plenty of 'love hotels', hostess clubs, adult shops and yakuza (Japanese mob) to go around. Even so, much like Amsterdam's equivalent, it's as much an entertainment spot and centre of nightlife as it is a red light district. Whilst I wouldn't go swearing in Japanese at any of the well-heeled, little-finger-deprived yakuza that hang out there, they will seldom even look at a foreigner, never mind cause them any trouble. Too much hassle.

Roppongi is slightly different in that it's really a foreigner hotspot - plenty of dodgy bars and clubs, particularly of the 'hostess' variety, which will invite you in and charge you hundreds of dollars for a drink and some chat time with a Japanese hostess. Technically you're paying for the drink, but argue at the price and expect a rude exit from the establishment. If there were anywhere in Tokyo you shouldn't go, it'd be here at night - but only because it's not very nice, as opposed to dangerous. During the day Roppongi has some rather spectacular architecture, and is home to a bunch of Western and Japanese companies, as well as a ton of embassies. Not really a hellhole by any standards.

As with any country, common sense rules. Make sure to keep your valuables in a safe place or tucked away on your person. If you're dangling a wallet full of holiday fun time yen as you saunter through a train station it's more likely someone will try to help you and point it out, but still, it's better not to in the first place. Don't leave luggage lying about either - it won't get stolen, but the police don't like that sort of thing in case it's something more sinister.

Long story short - at no point in Tokyo will you ever cross some boundary from 'nice part crime-wise' to 'holy christ it's the Baltimore projects'. Those boundaries don't really exist.

Comment: Agreed.  Was stationed in Japan for a year and a half and did my fair share of partying and touristy type things.  Never once found a place where I felt "unsafe".  As with most places on Earth, be polite and friendly and 99% of the time, you'll be just fine.  Don't bother trying to get into a place with a "No Gaijin" sign, though. Ain't happening.

Comment: From my experience, Roppongi is a great place to go at night if you want to go to some clubs. There are some foreigners that will help you if you need it. The only thing that you should take care is about your sources. If you don't know where to go, find two or three places beforehand by google or ask any group of people that is going to party. Just try to avoid the people that tries to get you into some dark clubs, which is basically ignoring everyone talking to you on the street (many people).

Comment: I found the touts to be pretty friendly to be honest. I just don't like the Roppongi clubs or vibe in general. As I say, perfectly safe, just not for me.