# Safety in Tokyo and Ueda

Tags: japan, safety, tokyo

I'm travelling to Japan in February next year. To be precise to either Kawasaki or Yokohama.

Are there specific areas we should avoid for safety reasons in Tokyo and Ueda?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome! A lot of questions, and if you have a chance to read the [help], you'll see this site doesn't really work like that. Generally one question per post, so that those who know the answer can answer those and help future people too. I'm putting on hold for now, but await your individual questions as we have a lot of people who have been to Japan recently (myself included!)

Comment: Should I make a seperate post for each question then? Wasnt sure if that would have been counted as spamming :/ @MarkMayo

Comment: Not spamming. But do search for an existing answer in each case.

Comment: @ZeouLs definitely not spamming, but as the other user said, make sure it hasn't been asked before, saves you time :D

Comment: @ZeouLs Are you referring to Ueda, Nagano, which is far away from Tokyo?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: @jpatokal that's correct, I'm referring to Ueda in Nagano, we will make a trip over there and some other places outside of tokyo

Comment: I'd avoid wading in Tokyo bay. You never know when Godzilla will attack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tokyo is **exceedingly safe**, particularly by American standards.  While Tokyo, like any large city, has both wealthier and poorer parts, there are no "slums" worthy of the label and the odds of being violently assaulted or mugged are virtually zero regardless of where you go.

The one potential exception is if you go to nightlife districts, notably Roppongi, *and* let yourself be lured by touts into adult entertainment clubs, where you *may* either get your drink spiked or just run up a ridiculous bill.  This is easily avoided by choosing your own places to go.

See also: [US State Department travel advisory for Japan](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Japan.html), and [this Q&A about Japan as a whole](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/safety-petty-crimes-mostly-in-japan?rq=1).

Answer (score 6):

Roppongi is an upscale and quite good neighborhood otherwise; just be careful when it comes to night life.

On the other hand, try to avoid the red light districts, such as Kabuki-cho and Shinjuku 2-chome. If you go, don't engage anyone and especially don't partake in "special" activities. Most likely you won't get mugged or anything, but do be careful.

Also, avoid missionaries and far-right protesters (i.e. people shouting with loudspeakers and who apparently are not campaigning politicians), as they occasionally pop up at the street. They won't do any harm to you, but conflict is more likely around them (plus they're really annoying).

As for Ueda, I have not been there but the city looks like an idyllic city in the mountains (but not middle of nowhere either). Therefore I would be even less concerned with safety there. Of course, if you do hike, pay attention to geological failure and animals as usual (and, in the winter, snowstorms). According to the comments, this basically means **stay on paved roads**.

Comment: *pay attention to geological failure* – +1, stay on paved roads in Japanese woods. Deep, moss-covered holes between rocks are one of the deadliest threats in Japan.

Comment: @Janka And, like, everywhere in the world. I would not go off paved roads in the wild, unless I get special warfare training in the future or something like that.

Comment: Oh, people over here do it every day in autumn to look for mushrooms. That's unadviseable if the ground is basically a big stone run loosely covered by moss.

Comment: @Janka I guess that depends on how "wild" the place is. Not so wild - probably OK, take caution. Middle of nowhere - probably not, there could be snakes even if there are no geological failures.

Comment: @xuq01 I'm an ex soldier, does that count as warfaret training? I'm pretty confident in my walking / hiking skills

Comment: @ZeouLs That was mostly an exaggeration. Just pay a lot of attention to holes, soft soil, snakes, etc.